# nonuniqueobjectexception on default ID generation in hibernates

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

Following code is throwing : **`nonuniqueobjectexception`** .

However when I use:
**@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)** every thing starts working fine.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CART")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @Column(name="cart_id")
    private long id;


@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Items {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;
```

I want to understand why it is failing with default ID generation strategy of hibernates.

Answer (score 0):

Well  nonuniqueobjectexception exception is thrown when an operation would break session-scoped identity.

This occurs if the user tries to associate two different instances of the same Java class with a particular identifier, in the scope of a single Session.

It can also mean Hibernate is not able to generate Unique Id's.

Having said that it is always advisable to use GeneratedValue type provided.

as

```
id = ggggg4g5h55hh6hhh7h7
```

is more complicated that

```
id = 2
```

This link will help you to understand it well.

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/